# Custom UI for ongoing calls in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, user-interface

I'm building an **Android Launcher** for the elderly, using **Android Studio**, and I'm trying to change how the *UI* of an **ongoing call** looks. I want to know if it's even possible.

I know I could do it by building a [Custom ROM](https://www.androidauthority.com/build-custom-android-rom-720453/), but that's not a solution for me. I'm asking here, because I can't find anything online about this. All I could find was [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/telecom/selfManaged).

I tried reading the last link 5 times now, but I can't figure out what to do. I feel like I'm overcomplicating something very simple. Remember, I don't want to change how calls are made, nor change any routines and listeners. All I want to change is the user interface.

What I want to change:
[Default ongoing android call look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BTLUJ.png)

Comment: Have you tried building a sample app following the guide "Build a calling app" (ie the link you posted)?

Comment: Yes. However, as I said, I don't want to change the way calls are made and received. The guide is very confusing since it does much more than I want. All I want is to change the interface.